# How can I create 2D, sprite-based reflections in HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: 2d, html5, html-canvas, reflection-rendering

I'm trying to create simple reflections in a 2D, sprite-based game using HTML5. I'm looking to recreate an effect like the one you'd often see in GBA games, such as Pokemon Emerald and Mother 3:

[image: Mirror and Water reflections in Mother 3 and Pokemon Emerald]

These days we don't really get to see many 2D games that pull off this kind of effects.  How could I achieve this with HTML5 Canvas?

Comment: Hmmm... Maybe flipping the sprite over and distorting it in someway? The Game Boy truly was amazing... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Draw the water

[image: water]

2. Draw your sprites, flipped upside-down about the water level, and with some effects

[image: reflection]

3. Draw the ground (this covers the reflection and water)

[image: ground]

4. Draw everything else normally

[image: everything]

http://jsfiddle.net/cgzrwhpn/

Comment: Thank you for answering. That is a good example but it uses Phaser (not pure Canvas/JS) and I'd also like some input on doing the Mother 3 reflection.

Comment: @Belohlavek what trouble are you having with pure Canvas/JS? As you can see, the concept is very simple; operations such as flipping and draw order can be done as simply in JS as any framework.

Comment: The other reflection is done by essentially the same means: Draw the reflected sprite first, then the mirror frame around it, and then the rest of the scene. Except instead of reflecting on an X-axis, reflect on the Z-axis, so the other side of the pixels become visible. (Ok ok, just kidding, draw a different sprite.) The key in both cases is that it's done with multiple drawings, all under your control. There isn't any special "reflection" going on, just artistry.

Comment: Thank you all for commenting. I just needed a full answer before marking it as accepted. Since they edited my original question to make it specific to one tech, I think is fair to only accept a complete answer! I'll take the logic explained here and ignore the Phaser part. Again thanks for the quick responses :)